# Rails and jQuery Ajax (POST) - error response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, post

I'm building an Rails app and I'm trying to do an AJAX call with jQuery. When I do the AJAX call (POST), I receive an error from my method. But I don't know what the problem is :(

Everything worked when I'm using the 'GET' method, but when I change it to 'POST', I'm receiving the error (and yes, I changed the route.rb :) )

jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/login/checkLogin/",
  dataType: "json",
  data: data,
  type: 'post',
}).done(function(response){
  console.log(response);
})
```

Method

```
ldap = Net::LDAP.new
ldap.host = "***"
ldap.port = ***
ldap.auth %[#{params[:login_username]}], params[:login_password]

if ldap.bind
 session['loggedin'] = true
 respond_with "1".to_json
else
 session['loggedin'] = false
 respond_with "0".to_json
end
```

The error message (coming from the console)

```
undefined method `"0"_url'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is backside of Rails magic :)
By default, Rails uses [ActionController::Responder](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Responder) to process respond_with if no block given or template is not available. For 'POST' method (REST 'create') and non-html formats like xml and json, it generates a response with encoded resource, status code (:success), and resource location. So it tries to find out the URI of the resource you have passed, and fails on this step.

Just pass `:location => nil` option to override defaults, or use explicit `respond_to` block

```
respond_with "0".to_json, :location => nil
```

or

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json {render :json => "0".to_json}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` for $.ajax({...})